# Regex for removing a /**/ comment in js

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I remove something like this from a string using regex in JavaScript?

```js
/*
    multi-line comment
*/
```

This is what I have tried:

```js
var regex = /(\/\*(^\*\/)*\*\/)/g;
string = string.replace(regex, '');
```

Comment: Wrong tool, use esprima and escodegen- JavaScript is not regular

Comment: I'd say that looks suspicously like C style comments. If not, there are no rules, and its simply `/\/\*.*\*\//` for greedy, `/\/\*.*?\*\//` for non-greedy.

Comment: Regular expressions cannot correctly remove multi-line comments from JavaScript. You can come close, but there will be edge cases that will break.

Comment: But, if C-syle rules, comments and quotes dance around to be first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like to match `/*` followed by any amount of text that does not contain `*/`, followed by `*/`, then you can use a regular expression, however it will *not* correctly remove block comments from JavaScript.

A simple example of where the pattern I described fails is:

```
var a = '/*'; /* block comment */
```

Note that the first `/*` will be matched even though it's contained in a string. If you can guarantee that the content you are searching within does not contain such inconsistencies, or are just using the regular expression to find places to make manual changes, then you should be reasonably safe. Otherwise, don't use regular expressions because they're the wrong tool for the job in this case; **you have been warned**.

---

To build the regular expression, you just have to break down my first sentence into its composite parts.

- `/` starts the regular expression literal
- `\/\*` matches the literal characters `/*`
- `[\s\S]*?` matches any character in a non-greedy manner
- `\*\/` matches the literal characters `*/`
- `/` ends the regular expression

All together you end up with:

```
/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//
```

The non-greedy matching is necessary to prevent a close comment (`*/`) from getting captured when multiple block comments are in a file:

```
/* foo */
var foo = 'bar';
/* fizz */
var fizz = 'buzz';
```

With the non-greedy matching,

```
/* foo */
```

and

```
/* fizz */
```

would be matched, without the non-greedy matching,

```
/* foo */
var foo = 'bar';
/* fizz */
```

would be matched.

Comment: did you try your lucky string? a = '/*'; /* javascript is not regular */ :D

Comment: @unixer, yes, I'm pretty certain that I explicitly stated that that specific example would fail for the pattern I described.

Comment: `[\s\S]` matches any whitespace character as well as any non-whitespace character. That's a more complex way of matching any character, which is also done by `.`.

Comment: @Arjan, no, [`.` does *not* match newline characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes). `[\s\S]` matches **every** character. They are not equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

All the answers that use a regular expression completely fail here for several cases:

```
var myString = '/*Hello World!*/'; // inside a string
var a = "/*b", c = /.*/g; // inside a string partially, and inside a regex literal

// /*
alert("This will not fire with the regular expressions, but works in JS");
// */
var/**/b = 5; // perfectly valid, replacing a comment with nothing is simply incorrect
```

For some of the more obvious ones. Regular expressions are simply not strong enough to parse comments correctly, they need to be aware of the language syntax.

So, a regular expression fails, what's left? A parser. Is it hard? Not really.

Let's look at the JavaScript syntax ourselves! The [section on comments](http://es5.github.io/#x7.4) states:

```
MultiLineComment ::
    /* MultiLineCommentCharsopt */
```

That's good, it means that when we're inside a multiline comment, we do not exit it until we reach `*/` and then we exit it immediately.

But when can comments appear? Pretty much anywhere outside of literals. Out of the 5 literals we have , multiline comment tokens can only appear in string literals and regexp literals.

```
function parse(code){
    // state
    var isInRegExp = false;
    var isInString = false;
    var terminator = null; // to hold the string terminator
    var escape = false; // last char was an escape
    var isInComment = false;

    var c = code.split(""); // code

    var o = []; // output
    for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
        if(isInString) {  // handle string literal case
             if(c[i] === terminator && escape === false){
                  isInString = false;
                  o.push(c[i]);
             } else if (c[i] === "\\") { // escape
                  escape = true;
             } else {
                  escape = false;
                  o.push(c[i]); 
             }
        } else if(isInRegExp) { // regular expression case
             if(c[i] === "/" && escape === false){
                 isInRegExp = false;
                 o.push(c[i]);
             } else if (c[i] === "\\") {
                 escape = true;
             } else { 
                escape = false;
                o.push(c[i]);
             }
        } else if (isInComment) { // comment case
              if(c[i] === "*" && c[i+1] === "/"){
                  isInComment = false;
                  i++;
                  // Note - not pushing comments to output
              }
        } else {   // not in a literal
              if(c[i] === "/" && c[i+1] === "/") { // single line comment
                   while(c[i] !== "\n" && c[i] !== undefined){ //end or new line
                       i++;
                   }
              } else if(c[i] === "/" && c[i+1] === "*"){ // start comment
                    isInComment = true;
                    o.push(" "); // add a space per spec
                    i++; // don't catch /*/
              } else if(c[i] === "/"){ // start regexp literal
                    isInRegExp = true;
                    o.push(c[i]);
              } else if(c[i] === "'" || c[i] === '"'){ // string literal
                    isInString = true;
                    o.push(c[i]);
                    separator = c[i];
              } else { // plain ol' code
                    o.push(c[i]);
              }
        }
    }
    return o.join("");
}
```

I just wrote this in the console, it's long - but can you see how simple it is? It's really simple in concept - it just keeps track of where in the code it is and based on that consumes the word.

Let's try it:

```
parse("var a = 'hello world'"); // var a = 'hello world' 
parse("var/**/a = 'hello world'"); // var a = 'hello world' 
parse("var myString = '/*Hello World!*/';"); // var myString = '/*Hello World!*/';
parse('var a = "/*b", c = /.*/g;'); // var a = "/*b", c = /.*/g;
parse("var a; /* remove me please! */"); // var a;
parse("var x = /* \n \n Hello World Multiline String \n \n */ 5"); // var x =   5
```

Comment: The parser is fairly straightforward, let me know if I can help you with that.

Comment: You had a couple quote characters that were a bit mixed up, I think I fixed them, but double check because nested quotes are easy to mess up.

Comment: @zzzzBov oh cool, thanks, hope it's just the examples. I tested it in JSFiddle and it seemed to work.

Answer (score -1):

Following will remove commands and also spams from Javascript.

```
 var regex = /^(\s*[^\s]*\s*)$/g;
 string = string.replace(regex, '');
```

Hope this will help...